# Tooltips don't clear on IE8

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm building an application using Highcharts and need to support IE8 for a large enterprise customer.

This is the issue I'm seeing. Whenever I hover over a point the tooltip shows up as expected. However, when I move the mouse away the border of the tooltip remains. This happens for every point, so I end up with several partial tooltips on the chart. If I hover over the same point again, I get another tooltip. See the picture for an example. (I'd make a fiddle, but jsfiddle doesn't support IE8).

I've tried grouping tooltips, but this doesn't seem to help. I've removed any tooltip formatters, but that doesn't seem to help either. I'd love to support tooltips on IE8. Any ideas what's happening and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is this only happening on your charts, or arre you seing it on the highchart examples and in jsfiddle ?

Comment: @SteveP Unfortunately I can't check jsFiddle, since it doesn't support IE8. But I can replicate the issue locally with the chart from http://docs.highcharts.com/#your-first-chart

Comment: @cfs any chance you are using jQuery 2.0? jQuery 2.x doesn't support IE8.

Comment: @RealityExtractor Nope; not jQuery 2.0. I've tried with jQuery 1.9, 1.8, and 1.7, and still have the same issue

Comment: Which version of IE do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! I didn't specify a `doctype`, so the page was rendering in IE8 Quirks mode. I added `<!doctype html>` to change to Standards mode and this resolved the issue.