# Highcharts tooltips flickering ON IE8

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4iNK.gif)[image]Hi I am using below code to plot the charts througs Highchart API. By this tooltips are working fine on firefox and also on chrome but on IE tooltips are flickering. and as we move mouse tooltips remain for some sort of time while other has appear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var chart=new Highcharts.Chart({
                            chart : {
                               zoomType: 'xy',
                               spacingRight: 20,
                               renderTo : "container",
                               type : graphType
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                enabled: true,
                                followPointer: true
                            },
                            title : {
                                text : graphTitleForChart
                            },xAxis : {
                                type: 'datetime'  
                            },credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            legend: {
                                align: 'right',
                                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                layout: 'vertical'
                            },
                            yAxis : {
                                min : 0
                            },
                            plotOptions :{
                                area: {
                                 stacking: 'normal',
                                 lineColor: '#666666',
                                 lineWidth: 1,
                                 marker: {
                                    enabled : false,
                                    symbol : 'circle'
                                    }
                                },
                                column: {
                                 stacking: 'normal',
                                 pointPadding : 0,
                                 lineColor: '#666666',
                                 lineWidth: 0,
                                 marker: {
                                    enabled : false,
                                    symbol : 'circle'
                                    }
                                },
                                pie: {
                                 allowPointSelect : true

                                },
                                line: {
                                 marker: {
                                    enabled : false,
                                    symbol : 'circle'
                                    }
                                },
                                series: {
                                    events: {
                                        legendItemClick: function(event) {

                                            var seriesIndex = this.index;
                                           var series = this.chart.series;
                                           if(this.name == 'Select All'){

                                                if(this.visible){
                                                    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        series[i].hide();
                                                    }
                                                }else{
                                                    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
                                                    {    
                                                        series[i].show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                return false;    
                                           }else if(series.length > 1){

                                               var i;
                                               for (i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
                                               {    
                                                   if(!series[i].visible){
                                                        break;         
                                                   }
                                               }  
                                           }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }    
                            },
                            series : arrSeries
                });

            });
```

In this, graphType will containe either of 'area','column','pie','line' .
Please tell me what's wrong in this. 
Also when all the graph series have 0 values then at y-axis 0 line shows in the middle of y-axis, how can I fix origin of Y and X axis to (0,0)

Comment: Could you attach "arrSeries" object ?

Comment: could you please tell me how to attach the object. I have firebug in firefox, and IE developer tools both. and I have write the data which is in the arrSeries in post, but not the name part

Comment: How your arrSeries looks like, which values have? You can use console.log(arrSeries);

Comment: Which version of Highcharts do you use?

Comment: Could you test this exmaple http://jsfiddle.net/SYFbu/ problem also appears? I used HC 3.0.2 and I cannot reproduce this issue, Whcih version of IE8 do you have?

Comment: Problem appears in my example?

Comment: I try your given link but at my system it does not render, I have attach the image of your link in My IE , please watch that

Comment: Let's try to open http://jsfiddle.net/SYFbu/show

Comment: Yes , tool tips are working fine in this

Comment: but , why tool tip issues occur from My Program

Comment: Try to update to 3.0.2 and update my example with your code, as full example.

Comment: Error which you recive (attached in screenshot) is caused by jsfiddle, not by highcharts. Jsfiddle are prepared by third party developers, so we cannot be responsobile for this compatiblity. but examples with /show in the end of URL work properly.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan for your communication regarding this issue. Now I found the issue was of doctype. When I put <!DOCTYPE HTML> then it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104345/tooltips-dont-clear-on-ie8) caused by IE8 being in Quirks Mode. This is most likely happening because you haven't specified a doctype.

Use `<!doctype html>` to change to Standards mode and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a representative demo using some of your data I cannot reproduce the "flickering" of the tooltip.
I will say that the answer to you second question is no, you cannot set the chart to show just the mutual positive area when all your points are not defined or are all 0. This is a result of how HighCharts is trying to determine the size of the chart. It does not do well with no points or with all 0 yAxis values.

Answer (score 0):

Just put <!DOCTYPE HTML> before HTML tag, then tool tips will not flicker.