# Highcharts drag and drop produces low performance on ie8

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, highcharts, web-worker

I have a scenario of drag and drop of highcharts series.

Here is a simplified use case example:
http://embed.plnkr.co/jTdVjm/preview

In this use case I have 5 couples of line and scatter series. The scatter series contain only a small subset of the samples in the line series. 
Following recommendations such as [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#optimize-performance), I've disabled animation, shadow, mouse tracking and marker for the line series. The scatter series can be drag and dropped, whereas the corresponding line series follows it.

In ie8 this produces very poor performance. I get reasonable performance only when I restrict to about 100 samples per series.

I also use series.setData when updating the series data, which is supposed to be the fastest way to change series data.

The requirement is for the line series to follow the scatter series while dragging.
Can anyone suggest other optimization before I get my hands really dirty?

I'm planning on using some optimized web-workers mechanism, so whenever I'm dragging the scatter series, only one mouse-move event will be handled at a time. That is - if a mousemove event occurs, than either it will be ignored or it will cause an interrupt of a previous mousemove event, so only a few of the mouse move events will be handled.

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Have you checked this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983987/highcharts-tooltips-flickering-on-ie8 ?

Comment: I must admit I haven't, but anyway - my example contains the <!DOCTYPE html> tag, so it's not the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: That was just and idea ;-) Don't forget to check related posts (right column) as Highcharts vs IE8 seem to be a recurrent subject

Comment: You need to be aware that IE<9 uses VML instead of SVG, which has no good performance.

Comment: Yes, I know...
I tried to optimize the drag and drop by ignoring any mouse move event while another mouse move event is being processed.
Ironically, I managed to improve (theoretically) performance in chrome, but not in IE8, since it's single threaded. It seems that there's nothing much I can do except to reduce number of samples (e.g. weekly instead of daily), but that's something we already did ages ago....